# how to import proper python module on virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module, vscode-debugger

I have this problem, that cannot import torch and torchvision well.

Currently, I am using the virtual environment, juneon, using Anaconda.

I think I set the library path and python path properly like the first following image.

[image: the library path and python path I set]

Running the python file does not matter, However, during debugging, they cannot find those modules via VSCODE. I posted the second following image I've been seeing.

[image: second image]

What should I check in order to solve the problem?

FYI, the third image is my file tree
[image: tree]

Please let me know what I am missing!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you setup visual code to use virtualenv? Have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments ?

Comment: well, I downloaded VSCODe in my local. and then I activated my conda environment. Then it happended.

Comment: BTW, I solved this problem by Selecting Interpreter!! I appreciate it a lot!